# AWS Load Balancing for both external and internal URL paths

Tags: amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, elastic-load-balancer

Is it possible to set up an App Load Balancer on AWS to be both internal and externally accessible? For example, a web application has an admin dashboard located at /admin and it'd be great to have that only accessible via a VPN and have the rest of the site public.

Answer (score 0):

The `scheme` (`internet-facing` | `internal`) is a property of the load balancer itself, and can't be controlled independently at the listener level, so no you won't be able to have one rule's path only resolvable within your VPC, and another rule Internet facing.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLoadBalancer.html